# How to write Three days completed condition in sql

Tags: sql

I have a column in table (name - dInsertedDate) that contains date of employee data received. I need to show all details post three days of data received.

```
select * from tbl_Emp where convert(date,dInsertedDate +3, 105) <= convert(date,getdate(),105)
```

Is the above condition right? Will it give me the satisfied output?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
select * from tbl_Emp where dinserted >= dateadd(day,-3,getdate())
```

Comment: assuming you are using mssql

Comment: thanks for the answer. Will definitely use dateadd function. Also, what about the condition I have used is it correct and will it give the right output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DATEADD function in sql to add or subtract from date

```
DECLARE @Date datetime = DATEADD(DAY, -3, getdate())

select * from tbl_Emp where dInsertedDate >= @Date
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could u also review the condition I have used is it right and will it give the right output?

Comment: That depend on your case, are test the code? and what the output you want?